# Selecting data based on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still newbie with database and mysql stuff, i want to learn how to use `JOINs`.I'm sorry i just have no idea to put this case on words. I hope all of You can understand by looking these data. Here's the tables with records:

```
Table student 
student_id | student_name 
-------------------------
1            Ana
2            Billy
3            Connor

Table comp 
comp_id | subj_id | comp_name  
--------------------------
1         24         Run       
2         24         Swim       
3         24         Jump
4         25         Eat    

Table comp_mark 
semester | subj_id | student_id | comp_id | mark
-------------------------------------------------
1          24        1            1         7
1          24        1            2         4
1          24        1            3         6
1          24        2            1         4
1          24        2            2         8
1          24        3            1         9
```

I'm expecting the result something like this from the query selecting `comp_mark` table(update):

```
student_name | semester | subject_id | comp_id  | mark
-------------------------------------------------------
Connor        1          24           1          9
Connor        null       24           2          null
Connor        null       24           3          null
```

is there anyone can help me with this? Thank a ton

UPDATE

I've tried this (Guillaume Poussel's query) and ORDER it by student_name :

```
 SELECT s.student_name, cm.semester, c.subj_id AS subject_id, c.comp_id, cm.mark
 FROM student s
 CROSS JOIN comp c
 LEFT JOIN comp_mark cm ON s.student_id = cm.student_id
 AND cm.subj_id = c.subj_id
 AND cm.comp_id = c.comp_id
 ORDER BY s.student_name
```

The results:
[image]

Comment: Show us what you have you tried so far?

Comment: `AND cm.semester = '1' 
 AND cm.subj_id = '1' ` semester and subj_id are _not_ character columns, but INTEGER. You should compare them to int values, like `AND cm.semester = 1 
 AND cm.subj_id = 1` (I know mysql does this typeconversion automagically, but that should also be considered a serious flaw)

Comment: To filter out line you don't need, just add a WHERE clause. For example, `WHERE cmm.subj_id = 24 AND cm.student_id = 4`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT s.student_name, cm.semester, c.subj_id AS subject_id, c.comp_id, cm.mark
FROM student s
CROSS JOIN comp c
LEFT JOIN comp_mark cm ON s.student_id = cm.student_id AND cm.subj_id = c.subj_id AND cm.comp_id = c.comp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to add a cross join to get all the possible values from comp. Something like this:-

```
 SELECT s.student_name, c.subj_id, s.student_id, c.comp_id, cm.mark 
 FROM student s
 CROSS JOIN comp c
 LEFT OUTER JOIN comp_mark cm 
 ON s.student_id = cm.student_id 
 AND cm.semester = '1' 
 AND cm.subj_id = '1'
```